# Change UIButton with image "touchable" area

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a button with a little X image but if I don't touch in inside the X, and I mean, touch the lines in the X it don't get touched.

How can I make it to launch touch event over the button frame area and not in the image borders?

Comment: I check it in a common iPhone app and it works fine. What kind of app are you developing?

Comment: It's like when I touch the transparent part of the image the `IBAction` is not been fired.

Comment: Yes, I understand what is your problem. I experimented the same problem working with Today extensions, but it works fine in a normal iOS app. So again, in what kind of application are you getting this problem?

Comment: It's a normal Iphone application and I'm setting the image to UIButton thought the storyboard

Comment: Try creating a new project and add just a button with the image that you want. Add a touch event to it and see if occurs the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
IBAction func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject, event: UIEvent) {
    let clickedBtn = sender as UIView;
    if let touch = event.touchesForView(clickedBtn)?.anyObject() as? UITouch {
       //get the touch.locationInView(clickedBtn) and check the rect is inside the X (use CGRectContainsPoint to do this).
    }
}
```

Comment: But the `IBAction` is not been fired, that's what I mean, if you touch it, you have to touch the X lines, like the non transparent portion of the image.